# Adding a picture on an MMS

Tags: java, android, android-intent, mms

I've tried to add a picture on a MMS, weirdly, it's work on email but it does not show up on MMS. Any idea? I just want to open the current text message app then write a message with an image.

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent mms = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
mms.setType("image/*");
mms.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
mms.putExtra("sms_body", ConstanteService.getShareURL(this.context));    
mms.putExtra("address", phoneTxt);
mms.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mms,"Send"));
```

Comment: It should launch any application which handles Intent.SEND actions. You need to choose the messaging app for sending as MMS.

Comment: My problem is the image does not show up on text message app but it works perfectly on email app.